# Integration send byte array in SOAP request, .NET and apache camel

Tags: java, .net, soap, apache-camel, integration

i try sent SOAP request conteins document Content in byte array to external service by .NET application. And i got this error message

> org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader: Unexpected character 'H' (code 72) in prolog; expected '<'
>    at [row,col {Unknown-source}]: [1,1].

When i coppy generated request message and sent in SOPA UI, it's working well. Do you know, what its may be?

Comment: There is a `H` where a `<` should be (at the first position).

Comment: I think its not it, becouse like i said when i sent this generated request by SOAP UI. Its working.

Comment: why do you  not use just a string instead of byte array? and from where do you copy your request to SOAPUI? is it from tcpmon (or such) or what?

Comment: You will need to provide the actual request your sending for us to help you.

Comment: Request looks like this below and this is not pass, but when content is very small everythink working. But very curuis is that when i coppy and sent request message to soap ui its pass.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v1:Info>
         <requestId>XXX</requestId>
         <consumerId>21342</consumerId>
      </v1:Info>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:importDocument>
        .
<documentContent>JVBUNJeLjz9MNCjM2MCAwIG9iag08PC9MaW5lYXJpemVkIDEvTCA0MTc2NzQvTyAzNjIvRSAyM<rest of content>iUlRU9GDQo=</documentContent>.
      </v1:importDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>